# Data population

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a scenario like

Table1

```
Id.   Name.     Age.    City
1.    Aaa.      20.     Ccc
2.    BBB.      12.     Ccc
```

Table 2

```
Id.   Name.     Age.    City
1.    FFF               Ccc
```

Now all I need is based on the city (ccc is common in both )
I will have to change age value in table b and the expected output is

```
Id.   Name.     Age.    City
1.    FFF       20.     Ccc
2.    FFF       12.     Ccc
```

Comment: Hint:   `JOIN` should do it.

Comment: Checkout the MERGE statement if you're looking to update and insert

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Table1.Id, Table2.Name, Table1.Age, Table1.City
FROM Table1
INNER JOIN Table2
ON Table1.City=Table2.City
```

It's easier if you tabulate the table name and the values in your question.
(use code block)

Comment: Please mark as answer if it helped you solve the problem... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just Use a simple INNER JOIN :

```
SELECT t1.ID, t2.name, t1.Age, t1.City
  FROM Table1 t1 JOIN Table2 t2 on ( t1.City = t2.City );
```

[*SQL Fiddle Demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/2c59c/2)